# Promise { <pending> }

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, javascript, etherscan

I am trying to get transactions done by each wallet by using Etherscan API. However, I am getting `Promise { <pending> }.`

Can someone please tell how to solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
const ethapi = require('etherscan-api').init(process.env.ETHAPI)



    async function getAddress(Address) {
        let tx = await ethapi.account.txlist(Address, 1, 'latest', 1,10, 'asc')
    
        return tx
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getTransactionFromAddress() works as intended, but you need to wait for the async function to resolve when you are logging the result. You can do this with:

```
getTransactionFromAddress('0x88a7EF2F047F8b07c6C917a6FD1A13438E9d8424').then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  // do whatever you want with the response
})
```

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Wait this not the right comment anymore? it is not working I am getting an errro with "." before then